# Convert array to object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How is possible to convert my array:

```
["Collaboration", "Personal", "Services", "Financial", "Enginerring", "Infrastructure", "Application", "null"]
```

to array of objects:

```
["title": "Collaboration", "title":"Personal", "title":"Services", "title":"Financial", "title":"Enginerring", "title":"Infrastructure", "title":"Application", "title":"null"]
```

I'm doing something like:

```
var mainmenu = [];
for(var i=0; menus.length > i;i++){
    mainmenu[i] = "{title:"+menus[i]+"}";   
}
```

but I got:

```
["{title:Collaboration}", "{title:Personal}", "{title:Services}", "{title:Financial}", "{title:Enginerring}", "{title:Infrastructure}", "{title:Application}"]
```

So How is possible to do it without double-quotes?

Comment: What you show as an "array of objects" does not exist in JavaScript. Do you mean `[{title: "Collaboration"}, {...}, ...]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var data = ["Collaboration", "Personal", "Services", "Financial", "Enginerring", "Infrastructure", "Application", "null"];
var result = data.map(function (title) {
  return { title: title };
}) 

console.log(result);
```

in your code problem that you are using `String` instead of `Object`, remove `"`

```
  mainmenu[i] = { title:  menus[i] };
               ^^^    ^^ ^^      ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are creating strings instead of actual objects. Create objects like this:

```
mainmenu[i] = {
    title: menus[i]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

es6

```
var data = ["Collaboration", "Personal", "Services", "Financial","Enginerring", "Infrastructure", "Application", "null"];
data.map(function(title) {
    return {
        title: title
    }
})
```

es5

```
for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
    data[i] = {title: data[i]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example where `Array.from()` can be used:

> The **Array.from()** method creates a new Array instance from an
>   array-like or iterable object.
>
> In ES6, class syntax allows for the subclassing of both built-in and
>   user defined classes; as a result, class-side static methods such as
>   `Array.from` are **"inherited"** by subclasses of Array and create new
>   instances of the subclass, not Array.

```js
var data = ["Collaboration", "Personal", "Services", "Financial", "Enginerring", "Infrastructure", "Application", "null"];
console.log(Array.from(data, x => ({title : x})));
```